# C# Form Size won't not set

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

i have a panel in a form and i load another form in this. this new loaded form have a picture box and the picture was larger as the main form. i want to scroll in the new form and show the picture. i set the size of the new form in code but in the breakpoint i can see the size show the right settings but if i show the settings in a message it show the false settings.

here the code

```
Form maleTree = new maleTreeForm(maleTreePanel);
        maleTree.TopLevel = false;
        maleTreePanel.Controls.Add(maleTree);

        Form maletreeForm = maleTreePanel.Controls.Find("maleTreeForm", true).FirstOrDefault() as Form;
        PictureBox pictureBox = maleTreePanel.Controls.Find("maletreePictureBox", true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;            
        maletreeForm.Size = new Size(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);
        MessageBox.Show(maletreeForm.Size.toString());
```

the picturebox.width show in breakpoint 2300, but in messagebox 1300.
i want to set the full 2300 how i can solve this ?
this is the result
[image]
you see in the right the scroll bar is not completly down but the image end

Comment: If you continue after your breakpoint, does it then size itself appropriately?  I.e. is the problem only that the MessageBox isn't reporting the updated information?

Comment: no the real problem is the picture dont show complete in the larger panel. it breaks and i think the problem are there false settings. i update the question

Comment: The false settings may be a false issue.  If I recall correctly, setting the Size pushes an event on to the message queue.  Until that event is processed, you won't find any update in the UI.  (If that's true, you can insert `Application.DoEvents()` between setting the size and calling your Messagebox, and you'll then get a correct answer.)

Comment: Start removing that message box. It is useless and could wreak havoc on the normal flow of events. If you want to check the size use a System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print and observe the values in the output window of Visual Studio

Comment: i tried it but the false numbers shown again. and i remove the messagebox and use Debug.Print but again, false settings

Comment: Windows can perhaps not set the width and height higher than the screen resolution?

Comment: It is not sensible code, you force the form to be only as large as a child control on that form.  That only ever comes to a good end if the form is borderless and the child control covers all of the form's client area.  Get ahead by *not* forcing the form size, update the question to tell us what goes wrong then.